# Incorrect syntax and exceptions thrown when trying to add a column pragmatically with c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having trouble with exceptions being thrown with the following syntax:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User Groups] ADD " + ColumnName + " VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL", 
    connection
);
```

Error says its an error somewhere near `VARCHAR`. Can't work out what the issue is, please someone enlighten me: :)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer... Please tag your question with the relevant one.

Comment: And can you post the value of `ColumnName`, and the error message?

Comment: @OJB1, There might be some data exist on the table column. Check your details exception message. It may give you clear view whats going wrong with your syntax.

Comment: Are you sure that variable `ColumnName` contains something? Can you exhibit a value that is actually causing an error?

Comment: Post value of ColumnName and the exact error message

Comment: I suggest you capture the entire SQL string in a variable, then pass that variable to the SqlCommand. That way you can see (debug/watch) the entire string exactly as it will be sent to SQL Server. Once you have that, cut and paste it into SQL Management Studio and try to run it; the error will then be obvious, as the IDE will tell you exactly where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the column name in square brackets:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User Groups] ADD [" + ColumnName + "] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL", 
    connection
);
```